# Temporarily Stop All Microsoft Windows Defender Processes In Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-defender

I'm running a huge sync job and Microsoft Windows Defender is hogging a ton of memory and creating a lot of disk I/O requests on my drive as well.

I know how to disable Windows Defender but I do not want to reboot my PC while this sync in going on to disable it. I also turned off real-time protection but that did not accomplish freeing the memory up like I expected.  I really just need to stop the `MsMpEng.exe` application.

Is it possible to temporarily stop Windows Defender application and then start it again without needing to reboot the PC?

Comment: So how do you suspend the wretched thing With a reboot.  The idea of running some unknown software from the web to suspend anti virus does not feel like a good idea.

Comment: I think your missing the point to my question @tuntable because I'm not trying to "suspended with a reboot".  The whole point was for me to free up the memory.  I wanted to suspend the antivirus so that I could gain that memory back.  A reboot would do this but I wanted to avoid a reboot because I was in the middle of a large copy job.  And at what point do you think that I am trying to run some "unknown software"?  I never said anything like that at all.  I think you just got the wrong idea about my question.  There are many situations when one would want to stop antivirus software.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### A Step-by-Step Guide to Temporarily Disabling Windows Defender and then Re-Enabling it on Windows 10

### *Initial One-Time Setup #1 - #4 per PC*

**1. Make a Windows Defender Folder Exclusion**

- First to start, create a new folder on your "C" drive or somewhere you can access and name it **DefenderExclusions**.
- Press the **Windows Key** one time, start typing "**Windows Defender**" and click it once you see it.
  [image: Windows Defender]
- From **Windows Defender** click on **Settings**
  [image]
- Go to **Windows Defender** and in the **Exclusions** area click the "**Add an exclusion option**"
  [image]

  - Click the "**Exclude a folder**" option

  [image]

  - Select the **DefenderExclusions** folder location you created above when the **Select Folder** window opens and then select the "**Exclude this folder**" option
    [image]

---

**2. [Download the NoDefender App](http://amd64fre.com/pub/apps/NoDefender.zip)**

- Download the [**NoDefender App**](http://amd64fre.com/pub/apps/NoDefender.zip) and it should save as a zip file named **NoDefender.zip**. 
  [image]
- Open the **NoDefender.zip** file and then *right-click* and select **Copy** on the file within it named **NoDefender.exe**
- Go to the **DefenderExclusions** folder location you created and setup the Windows Defender Exclusion, right-click and then paste to save the **NoDefender.exe** into this folder.

---

**3. Create Disable Defender Script**

- Save the below logic to a text document in the **DefenderExclusions** and name it to **DisableDefender.cmd**

**DisableDefender.cmd Script**

```
@ECHO ON

"%ProgramFiles%\Windows Defender\MSASCui.exe"
PING -n 3 127.0.0.1 > nul
"C:\DefenderExclusions\NoDefender.exe"

GOTO :EOF
```

---

**4. Create Enable Defender Script**

- Save the below logic to a text document in the **DefenderExclusions** and name it to **EnableDefender.cmd**

**EnableDefender.cmd Script**

```
@ECHO ON

sc start WinDefend enable
PING -n 3 127.0.0.1 > nul
NET START "WdNisSvc"
PING -n 3 127.0.0.1 > nul
NET START "WinDefend"
PING -n 3 127.0.0.1 > nul
"%ProgramFiles%\Windows Defender\MSASCui.exe"

GOTO :EOF
```

---

### Disabling Windows Defender

1. Double-click the **DisableDefender.cmd** batch file saved in the **DefenderExclusions** location setup previously.
2. When **Windows Defender** opens, click on the **Settings** option and be sure the **Windows Defender** option is selected on the left.

   [image]
3. Turn **off** **Real-Time Protection**, **Cloud-based Protection**, and the **Automatic sample submission** options.
   [image]
4. It is expected to see the warning message pop up in the lower right-hand corner of the task bar indicating that **Spyware and unwanted software protection** may be disabled with the red X.
   [image]
5. You will notice the **Windows Defender** app screen is more red than green now, the **PC Status: At risk** is showing, and the **Real-time protection** is **off**; just minimize that window for now.
   [image]
6. Double-click the **NoDefender.exe** file previously saved in the **DefenderExclusions** location. If the **User Account Control** message pops up select the **Yes** option to run it
7. Select **Next** in the **NoDefender** app window
   [image]
8. Select **Next** again in the **NoDefender** app window
   [image]
9. Click on the **Disable Window Defender** option in the **NoDefender** app window and then select the **Next** option.
   [image]
10. You should then see the **NoDefender** app window saying it's **Done** and that Window Defender should be disabled, select the **Exit** option.
    [image]
11. Now if you go back to the **Windows Defender** app window, you should notice that the **Virus and spyware definitions** with an **Out of date** status
    [image]
12. Now it is time to run the process(es) or whatever that needs to run with Windows Defender being disabled. Let everything finish and then once you are ready to re-enable Windows Defender, follow the **Enabling Windows Defender** section below.

---

### Enabling Windows Defender

1. Double-click the **EnableDefender.cmd** batch file saved in the **DefenderExclusions** location setup previously and give it a few seconds to finish and pop up the **Windows Defender** app window.
2. When the **Windows Defender** app window opens you should notice the **Real-time protectio**n is **On** and the **Virus and spyware definitions** have a value of **Up to date** now.
3. You want to select the **Settings** option from the **Windows Defender** app window again.
   [image]
4. Turn **On** **Real-Time Protection**, **Cloud-based Protection**, and the **Automatic sample submission** options.
   [image]

Now **Windows Defender** is re-enabled again.

---

As per the comment:

> The point of this question was to actually start the application over
>   again causing it to release it's hold on all the memory it has
>   consumed. I have used registry entries that will stop the WD
>   application from running but that requires a reboot. I disable WD
>   (real-time protection) by just going into settings and turning off
>   real-time protection. If real-time protection is off WD is disabled,
>   if MsMpEng.exe is not running, WD is stopped. – [Arvo Bowen](https://superuser.com/users/311435/arvo-bowen)

### Testing Results of MsMpEng.exe Before and After Running the Process

Below is a screen shot of the results of the command line of `tasklist | FIND /I "ms"` which shows whether or not the **MsMpEng.exe** process is running in memory. This process appears to kill the process from memory when it's disabled, and it appears to have it start back up and running in memory when it's enabled.
[image]

---

As per the comment:

> OK so following these steps SOME of the results are true. 1) When I
>   click the "Disable Windows Defender" button, WD has two messages
>   (real-time and Antivirus protection) is turned off. After two seconds
>   the Antivirus message disappears and only the real-time is left. Also,
>   Virus and spyware definitions still show up to date (green check). –
>   [Arvo Bowen](https://superuser.com/users/311435/arvo-bowen)

I went ahead and downloaded the latest version of the NoDefender.exe app and triple-checked the process and it's working just as I wrote about above. If for some reason you do not follow the steps in the order I wrote, then it may not work as I wrote. In particular, you MUST complete the steps defined in the **Disabling Windows Defender** section for #3 and turn all three of those to **Off** before you run the **NoDefender.exe** app disabling process.

Comment: GREAT write-up!  After you run the NoDefender application does that actual STOP the MS Defender application (not just disable the mechanics)?

Comment: Yea, I'm sure it does but my concern is that it's just "disabling" the application as opposed to "stopping" the application.  The point of this question was to actually start the application over again causing it to release it's hold on all the memory it has consumed.  I have used registry entries that will stop the WD application from running but that requires a reboot.  I disable WD (real-time protection) by just going into settings and turning off real-time protection.  If real-time protection is off WD is disabled, if MsMpEng.exe is not running, WD is stopped.

Comment: Until I confirm the MsMpEng.exe application stops I don't want to give the check yet.  But you have defiantly earned the +1 from me for your time spent on a great answer that is very helpful!

Comment: OK so following these steps SOME of the results are true.  1) When I click the "Disable Windows Defender" button, WD has two messages (real-time and Antivirus protection) is turned off.  After two seconds the Antivirus message disappears and only the real-time is left.  Also, Virus and spyware definitions still show up to date (green check).

Comment: I'm using Win10 Pro, didn't you say you were using Win10 Home?  Maybe that's the reason?  It's just not killing "MsMpEng.exe" for me.  Maybe it will if I restarted or something.  Virus and spyware definitions are always "up to date".  But you have went way and beyond answering this question with proof it is working for you so the check is yours!  At this point my sync job is done and it's really a moot point for me.  Thanks for all the help though!

Comment: @ArvoBowen I'm running this on *Windows 10 Professional* as well. Try right-click run as administrator on **NoDefender.exe** & see if that makes any difference if you get a chance. If so, I will update my answer and get this included.  I cannot `TASKKILL /F /IM "MsMpEng.exe"` and get "**Access Denied**" on that command line even if I run CMD as administrator but the **NoDefender.exe** seems to kill it from memory using it with no right-click admin on my machine following the steps. Perhaps my account is a local admin and that's why? If you stumble across an answer, feel free to update me.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, been busy.  OK, so...  yes I have tried running it "as Administrator", yes I have local admin privileges, and yes I get the same thing when trying to manually kill it with task manager.  What about a domain?  Are you on a domain?  My PC is part of a domain, maybe that's the difference?

Comment: @ArvoBowen Now that's a good point, this was not attempted on a domain PC where perhaps there could be policies set restricting access to kill this process on the PC even though you're a local admin. Unfortunately in the business environments I support and maintain, and I'm the domain\systems administrator of, we do not use Windows Defender for AV so I have no way to test, etc. I would say see if someone that is domain administrator would try it or else have one of your domain admins help you find a solution and confirm that this is even allowable on this machine; they may not want this killed